# Created weighted sample points in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, land-classification, sample, weighted

I have a classified satellite image and I want to create a confusion matrix to check its accuracy. Instead of doing a "simple random sample", I want to do a weighted sample, where there is a higher preference for sampling areas with higher complexity in the landscape.

For example, imagine if you have a classified image of a coast. There will be homogenous areas which are completely sand or completely water, and more complex regions where there is vegetation, sand and water in close proximity. I would like to predominately sample these complex regions.

I seek a way to provide a weighting.

**Current Approach**

My current plan is to do an edge detection to act as a measure of complexity (areas with more classes should have more edges) and somehow use that to weigh the random sample point, so that sample points are more likely to occur in areas with a high number of classes/complexity.

In ArcGIS Pro, how do you do point sampling that is weighted?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have edited to add more details.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an untested idea from the top of my head for you to explore.

Try using the [Focal Statistics](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/focal-statistics.htm) tool using the *variety* statistic type; you would need to explore with different neighbourhood sizes. Then group the output into fewer classes using a reclassify tool. Perhaps these could then be vectorized and become the basis of your sampling areas.